# Update the value of a field in index based on its value in another index

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-painless

There's an `index_A` that contains say about `10K docs`. It has many fields like field_1, field_2, ...field_n and one of the fields is `product_name`.

Then there's another `index_B` that contains about `10 docs` only and is a master catalogue sort of index. It has 2 fields: `product_name` and `product_description`.
e.g

```
{
    "product_name" : "EES",
    "product_desc" : "Elastic Enterprise Search"
}
{
    "product_name" : "EO",
    "product_desc" : "Elastic Observability"
}
```

`index_A` contains many fields, from that one of the fields is `product_name`. index_A does `not` have the field `product_desc`

I want to insert `product_desc` field into each document in `index_A` such that the value of `product_name` in `index_A` matches value of `product_name` in `index_B`.

i.e. something like `set index_A.prod_desc = index_B.prod_desc where index_A.prod_name = index_B.prod_name`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch cannot do joins like that

the best approach would be to do this during indexing, using something like an ingest pipeline, or Logstash, or some other piece of code that pulls the description into the product document

Comment: Thanks Mark. Agree with your suggestion to use ingest pipeline. Any hints on how to do that using ingest pipeline? 

Build a map of 10 keys (`product_name`) and values (`product_desc`) and then set value if doc's key matches `product_name`? 

Will appreciate some sample code or hints.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/enrich-processor.html is just what you want